# How to fetch all images from a WordPress draft using PHP?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to fetch and download all the images from a new Gutenberg draft. It's really slow having to download each image for web optimization. So, I'm trying to create a plugin that automatically fetches all the images. Any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: Create a query to get the drafts, then `preg_match` the post's content to look for the values in `src` tag.